# Spring Boot and Keycloack

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, redhat, keycloak

I would like a help to make my spring boot applications safer.

I have a RESTful API currently with no security implemented.
This API is accessed by another spring boot application through HTTP requests (GET, POST, PUT ...).

Recently, I walked through a [REDHAT](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak/) tutorial which demonstrated how to make a safer spring boot application using keycloak.

I want to learn how can I use this security combination (springsecurity-keycloak) for a springboot application having a desktop application (also in java) as its client. Any advice would come in handy.

Thank you,
Celso

Answer (score 0):

You have  2 options here:

1) Either use [Keycloak Adapter](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-boot-adapter.html) for Spring boot.

2) Or just use Springs OAuth2 package with Keycloak (because Keycloak is just another OAuth2 server). Here is sample config that is working with JWT (based on shared key) passed from Keycloak:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices( createTokenServices() );
        config.resourceId(the aud claim that you setup under Keycloak/realm/mappers);
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultTokenServices createTokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore( createTokenStore() );
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    private TokenStore createTokenStore(){
        return createJwtTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore createJwtTokenStore() {               
        return new JwtTokenStore( createJwtAccessTokenConverter() );
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter createJwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(shared secret that is configured in keycloak client);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I really appreciated your attention.

If there is not an inconvenience, I'd like a little more of your help completing your answer in a more pratical aproach on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027176/simple-example-using-spring-boot-and-keycloack).


Again, thank you.